# Increment row depending on value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, row-number

I have a sql query below, where dtMontno could start from any month and am adding Row column manually as below :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count,
       MONTH(TourTbl.DT_Started) as dtMonthno, 
       DATENAME(YYYY, TourTbl.DT_Started) as dtYear,
       row_number() over (order by DATENAME(YYYY, TourTbl.DT_Started) asc,
                                   MONTH(TourTbl.DT_Started) asc ) as Row 
FROM TourTbl 
INNER JOIN BranchTbl ON TourTbl.BranchID = BranchTbl.BranchID 
INNER JOIN AgencyTbl on AgencyTbl.AgencyID = BranchTbl.AgencyID 
WHERE Cancelled = 0  AND 
      (TourTbl.DT_Started >= '2010/03/15' and 
       TourTbl.DT_Started <= '2012/03/15') AND 
      AgencyTbl.AgencyID in ( 245 ) and 
      BranchRODID > 0
group by datename(M, TourTbl.DT_Started), 
         DATENAME(YYYY, TourTbl.DT_Started), 
         MONTH(TourTbl.DT_Started) 
order by dtYear asc, dtMonthno asc
```

now my result is :

```
  count dtMonthno dtYear    Row
    6      5      2011      1
    8      6      2011      2
    2      7      2011      3
    23     8      2011      4
    126    9      2011      5
    101    10     2011      6
    85     11     2011      7
    92     12     2011      8
    115    1      2012      9
    102    2      2012      10
    48     3      2012      11
```

Is there any way to start the Row column depending on the dtMonthno and increment by one in the example above would start from 5 and end in 15?

Thanks

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the derivation of `Row` to:

```
row_number() over (order by YEAR(TourTbl.DT_Started) asc,
                            MONTH(TourTbl.DT_Started) asc ) +
min(YEAR(TourTbl.DT_Started)*12+MONTH(TourTbl.DT_Started)-1) OVER () % 12 as Row
```

Comment: @Sam1: The `row_number() over ...` part will count them, while the `min(...) over () % 12` will set the starting point for the count.

Comment: @Sam1 This is the most elegant solution. You just need to change __year(__ to __DATENAME(YYYY,__.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović: but still i get : Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Column 'TourTbl.DT_Started' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović: `year(` should return the year as a number, while `DATENAME(YYYY` should return it as a string.

Comment: @Sam1: This is probably because the rest of the query is grouping by `datename(YYYY`, rather than `year(` - you could change the query to replace `datename(YYYY` with `year(` throughout, just add `year(` to the grouping expression or change `year(` in the above expression to `cast(datename(YYYY...) as int`.

Comment: Yes, but his original query works with datename hence year() gives an error. @Sam1 should either change his original query to use year() or switch to DateName as it will be implicitly converted to int because of * 12.

Comment: yes it works except for one thing if I set the condition as : WHERE Cancelled = 0  AND (TourTbl.DT_Started >= '2011/12/16' and TourTbl.DT_Started <= '2012/03/15') then it will start row from 0 i.e. 0
1
2
3

Answer (score 1):

You can add month of first DT_Started date:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count,
       MONTH(TourTbl.DT_Started) as dtMonthno, 
       DATENAME(YYYY, TourTbl.DT_Started) as dtYear,
       row_number() over (order by DATENAME(YYYY, TourTbl.DT_Started) asc,
                                   MONTH(TourTbl.DT_Started) asc ) 
                            + substring(min(DATENAME(YYYY, [TourTbl].DT_Started) + right ('0' + str (MONTH([TourTbl].DT_Started), 2), 2)) over (), 5, 2) - 1 as Row
FROM TourTbl 
INNER JOIN BranchTbl ON TourTbl.BranchID = BranchTbl.BranchID 
INNER JOIN AgencyTbl on AgencyTbl.AgencyID = BranchTbl.AgencyID 
WHERE Cancelled = 0  AND 
      (TourTbl.DT_Started >= '2010/03/15' and 
       TourTbl.DT_Started <= '2012/03/15') AND 
      AgencyTbl.AgencyID in ( 245 ) and 
      BranchRODID > 0
group by datename(M, TourTbl.DT_Started), 
         DATENAME(YYYY, TourTbl.DT_Started), 
         MONTH(TourTbl.DT_Started) 
order by dtYear asc, dtMonthno asc
```

Comment: hi, row becomes this now : 5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
9
11
13

Comment: Changed again. Leaving it here to punish myself over the coming years :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would truncate the dates to months and group by those values, then obtain years, months and row numbers based on the truncated dates:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS count,
  MONTH(GroupMonth) AS dtMonthno,
  DATENAME(YYYY, GroupMonth) AS dtYear,  /* why do you want year as a string? */
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GroupMonth) + MONTH(MIN(GroupMonth) OVER ()) - 1 AS Row
FROM (
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, TourTbl.DT_Started), 0) AS GroupMonth
  FROM TourTbl 
  INNER JOIN BranchTbl ON TourTbl.BranchID = BranchTbl.BranchID 
  INNER JOIN AgencyTbl on AgencyTbl.AgencyID = BranchTbl.AgencyID 
  WHERE Cancelled = 0  AND 
        (TourTbl.DT_Started >= '2010/03/15' and 
         TourTbl.DT_Started <= '2012/03/15') AND 
        AgencyTbl.AgencyID in ( 245 ) and 
        BranchRODID > 0
) s
GROUP BY GroupMonth
```